# My sprites do not always respect collisions in Pygame

Tags: collision-detection, python, collision-resolution, pygame

I have a Player sprite (40x40 pixels) and Tiles (20x20 pixels) which build the terrain. At the 4 edges there are 2 rows or columns (depends on vertical or horizontal) of wall tiles. Those are the limits which the player should not be able to overpass and collisions player-wall are checked there.

Most of times, it recognizes collisions, but sometimes it doesn't. When I move the player until the map limit and it hits the wall tile, it stops, but sometimes if I continue trying to move it against the wall, it doesn't respect the collision and enters in the wall. At this point, once the player enters in the wall tile it can only moves over wall tiles...

So, am I doing something wrong or is it just a pygame collisions bug?

Here is the method to check collisions:

```
def checkCollision(self):
    from prueba import limitGroup
    listLimits = limitGroup.sprites()

    for i in range (0, len(listLimits)):
        if listLimits[i].kind == "wall" and self.rect.colliderect(listLimits[i]):
            return True

    return False
```

And here is the `update()` method to move the player.

```
def update(self):

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        mouseX, mouseY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            self.bulletsGroup.add(Bullet(pygame.image.load("bullet.png"),
                                          self.rect.x + (self.image.get_width()/2),
                                           self.rect.y + (self.image.get_height()/2),
                                            mouseX, mouseY))

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        if not self.checkCollision():
            self.rect.x += 10
        else:
            self.rect.x -= 10
    if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        if not self.checkCollision():
            self.rect.x -= 10
        else:
            self.rect.x += 10
    if key[pygame.K_UP]:
        if not self.checkCollision():
            self.rect.y -= 10
        else:
            self.rect.y += 10
    if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        if not self.checkCollision():
            self.rect.y += 10
        else:
            self.rect.y -= 10
```

Comment: If I were you I would start with a good `pygame` tutorial. Using a bunch of `if/else` statements is usually a newbie approach (your code repeats 4 lines, 4 times). Apart from that, you need to change the position of your objects according to the time elapsed between this frame and the previous frame, so that your movement is the same no matter the frame rate. The way you have done it, someone running your game at 10 FPS moves 100 pixels per second, someone running at 60 FPS move 600 pixels per second. One lag spike and the user is off screen or worse.

Comment: @Shiro a couple of things, the time between frames is the Delta Time? Would you share with me some of these tutorials? Veing honest, it's my first game and I don't know another way to move the player without statemets `if/else`

Comment: I am not using python or pygame. It should be something like this             `Velocity = Vector2.Normalize(new Vector2(1, 0)) * DeltaTime.TotalMilliseconds * Speed;` (for moving right and `speed = 10;`) and then `Position += Velocity;`